# Name for multiples of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, orthogonal-matrices

Is there a name for a matrix which is a multiple of an orthogonal matrix? I.e. a square matrix $A$ which satisfies the condition

$$A^TA = AA^T = \lambda I$$

where $\lambda$ is some scalar (which should perhaps be required to be non-zero) and $I$ is the identity matrix. Or in other words, a matrix whose rows and columns are orthogonal vectors of equal length $\sqrt\lambda$, but not neccessarily unit length, so not orthonormal.

I've thought about these objects twice in different contexts recently, and it feels like a concept that should have a name. So far I haven't been able to find such a name, though. Do you know an established name for these matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a (now deleted) comment, [user104254](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/104254/user104254) suggested the name

## Conformal matrices

Actually he suggested the keyword “conformal”, the combination was assumed by me.
That name is suppoerted by some papers on the web.

[*Conformal Matrices*](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~rauch/555/Conformal_Matrices.pdf) by Jeffrey Rauch in Corollary 4.2 uses the condition

$$M\,M^t=c^2\,I\qquad\text{with }M\text{ invertible and }c>0$$

and states in Definition 4.3 that matrices $M$ satisfying this equation are called **conformal**.

In [*Geometric Rigidity of Conformal Matrices*](http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/dfaraco/versionesoficiales/GeometricRigidity.pdf) by Daniel Faraco and Xiao Zhong, they define conformal matrices as

$$CO_+(n)=\{A\in M^{n\times n}:A=\rho R\text{, where }\rho\in\mathbb R_+\text{ and }R\in SO(n)\}$$

As far as I can tell, the two definitions are equivalent to one another and to my own statemement, at least over the reals. Both do explicitely exclude the case of $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Thank you for referring to me in your own answer. Upvoted.

Comment: This could be seen as a special case of the more general conformal transformation, where $M M^t = c^2 g$, for some symmetric $g$.  This is usually done when $g$ is a metric, although it's quite common in numerical treatments of general relativity, in which $g$ wouldn't be positive-definite.